# 2012 MacBook Air has wear spot on the bottom left

Tags: macbook-pro, damage

My mid-2012 MacBook Air has a spot on the bottom plate. The computer has never been dropped. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

[image: Wear Spot]

Comment: It *could* be a bad battery cell that has expanded and pushed the bottom of the case out just enough to scrape.

Answer (score 1):

I took the computer in to Apple, and they determined that the spot was the result of a bulge caused by a piece of foam on the speaker. They told me that the foam and its attached components were the wrong parts.

Answer (score 0):

Is that circle actually there in real life, or did you add that to highlight the mark?  The scratch could be caused by something as simple as some grit on a table.  The feet on the air doesn't keep it very far off a surface, so just sliding the laptop with some grit could do that.

Comment: The circle is part of the wear.